# Substract numbers In URL untill requirements are met

Tags: javascript, image, loops, url, roblox

Okay, so basically what i'm trying to do is getting the texture of a shirt,
this can be done by substracting the id by 1. For example here's a shirt: https://www.roblox.com/catalog/140183072/Green-Hoodie-With-Headphones
and if i do: https://www.roblox.com/catalog/140183071/Green-Hoodie-With-Headphones (substracted the id by 1) it will result in the shirt page where it shows the texture of the shirt (It will be an "Image"). However, this is not always the case, so i made a little javascript that checks if the page is a shirt or not.
    var assetcheck = document.getElementsByClassName("field-content")[0];
    var isasset = assetcheck.innerHTML;

isasset will contain the value, in the first url above it would be "Shirt", and in the second url it would be "Image", so if it's "Image" then it's good.

What i'm trying to do is make a script which keeps substracting 1 from the url untill it finds that it's on an "Image" page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: This is far too complex to answer in one question but you should look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions and https://wiki.greasespot.net/ for info on browser extensions and greasemonkey userscripts respectively.

Comment: If any more information is required, ill be happy to provide it. I somewhat made a "working" script but it kept crashing my browser so it's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work well:

```
function findImage(id)

-- Now create a loop that checks when it returns the image.

for i = id,(id-20),-1 do
 wait()
 local productInfo = game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):GetProductInfo(id)
 if productInfo.AssetTypeId == 1 then -- We found a winner!
  return(i)
 end
end
end

local img = findImage(140183072)
```

What that will do is call the function that will return the ID of the image into the variable "img".

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: For RobloxLua, this is an excellent awnser, however, I'm looking for a javascript solution to run in the browser. Thanks for the script though!

Comment: Actually, i can not even get the version you made to work, if i do print(img) it outputs nil?